# What is the right structured data for BrowserGames and VideoGames?

Tags: schema.org

I have 2 domains; each domain and each category is different, i am not into coding, so what is right and what is wrong for A) BrowserGames and B) VideoGames?

Domain 1 for Browsergames:

A)Code for Site with Genre-Category:

```
<div class="footerRating"><br><span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">Durchschnittliche Bewertung: 
<span 
itemprop="ratingValue">4.4</span>/5 - <span 
itemprop="reviewCount">13773600</span> Stimmen </span></div>
```

B)Code for Site with Game:

```
<div id="game_rate" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating"><div 
class='ratingLeftContainer'><div class='gameEstimateIcon spriteRatingBig3'>
<span itemprop="ratingValue">80%</span><meta itemprop="bestRating" 
content="100%"/></div></div><div class='ratingMiddleContainer'>Wie gefällt 
Dir das Spiel?<div class='iconline'><a class="spriteRatingMiddle0" 
href="javascript:void(0);" rel="autoimageswitch" title="Schlecht" 
onclick="rateGame('aTg1SDRDa01qZ3hNak0w',0,'intermediate_special');"></a> <a 
class="spriteRatingMiddle1" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="autoimageswitch" 
title="Mittel" 
onclick="rateGame('aTg1SDRDa01qZ3hNak0w',1,'intermediate_special');"></a> <a 
class="spriteRatingMiddle3" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="autoimageswitch" 
title="Gut" 
onclick="rateGame('aTg1SDRDa01qZ3hNak0w',2,'intermediate_special');"></a> <a 
class="spriteRatingMiddle4" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="autoimageswitch" 
title="Verdammt Gut!" 
onclick="rateGame('aTg1SDRDa01qZ3hNak0w',3,'intermediate_special');"></a>
</div></div><div class='clear'></div><span class="ratingCount"><span 
class="counterValue" itemprop="ratingCount">43315</span> &nbsp<span 
class="counterText">x bewertet</span></span></div>


<div id='maincontent_container'><div id='content' class="gamePage"><div 
id='flash_container'></div><div id="game_intermediate_special_container" 
class="gameContainer"><div id="game_site_content"><div 
id="game_intermediate_container" class=""><div class="breadcrumb"><div 
style="display: inline; float:left;"><a href="*URL deleted*" 
class="breadcrumbLink first" >Spiele</a>&nbsp; > &nbsp;</div><div 
style="display: inline; float:left;"><ol itemscope         
itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" style="display: inline;list-style: 
none;"><a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" 
href="*URL deleted*" title="Mädchen" class="breadcrumbLink"><span 
itemprop="name">Mädchen</span></a><meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
</li><li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" style="display: inline;list-style: 
none;"><span class="gameInfoBreadcrumbArrow">&nbsp; > &nbsp;</span> <a 
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="*URL 
deleted*" title="Kochen und Backen" class="breadcrumbLink"><span 
itemprop="name">Kochen und Backen</span></a><meta itemprop="position" 
content="2" /></li></ol></div>
```

Domain 2 for VideoGames:

A)Code for Site with Game:

```
<div class="stiRightColGameOverview" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<meta itemprop="name" content="Grand Theft Auto 5">
<div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
<p>
```

B)Code for Site with Genre-Category:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage">

<li class="pull-left text-center" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
<meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
<meta itemprop="bestRating" content="99">
<a href="/artikel/5548/1/"><span class="stiSpinxHigh"  
itemprop="ratingValue" title="spieletipps Wertung 95%">95</span></a><br/>
<a href="/artikel/5548/1/"><span class="stiAwardInfoText">Wir meinen</span>
</a>
</li>
```

What is wrong? Any improvements?
@unor:PLZhelpme

Comment: I don’t understand your problem. Why do you think that something is wrong? What do you want to achieve? What do you mean with "domain" in this context?

Comment: got a manual penalty. and i am not sure if its the wrong itemtype (creativework vs.softwareapplication vs game vs. videogame) or if the reason is that we try to implement rating stars on category sites. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don’t fully understand your problem. If you want to know why you got (and what to do to fix) your penalty (coming from a search engine, I guess), you might want to ask on [webmasters.se]. -- If you want a code review of your markup, you can ask on [codereview.se]. -- If you have a specific question about how to use Schema.org and/or Microdata, you can ask here on Stack Overflow.